# If electromagnetic waves can be generated by oscillation of a coil why can't light?

Tags: visible-light, electromagnetic-radiation, harmonic-oscillator, radio, antennas

I was recently reading how electromagnetic waves are generated using oscillation of a current in an antenna. Why is it that this principle cannot be used to generate light?

Answer (score 0):

It can be done. But the frequency has to be very high which makes it useless for practical purposes.

Comment: Just saying *it can be done* is not very useful. Can you extend your answer to explain **how** it can be done. It **can't** be done with regular conductors because their plasma frequency is too low.

Comment: Plus they would have to be very small to couple sufficiently strong to the short wavelength radiation to produce noticeable output.

Comment: I just meant it is theoretically possible. Sorry for the misunderstanding. I am searching if anything of this sort has been done experimentally. I'll notify.